# Visual Studio 2015 & ReSharper 2017.1 - Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I has used some past IDE, where I was able to tell the IDE not to format code in a particular block of code by adding syntax blocks (I don't recall the exact syntax) before and after the block of code.  I was wondering if there was something similar in Visual Studio 2015/ReSharper 2017.1?

There is a block of javascript code in a js file that on each save, formats the block and I do not want it formatted.  I do want the js file to be formatted but not a certain block of javascript.

Yes, I can hit the ctrl-Z on each save but this seems cumbersome. Older IDEs are able to, just wandering if I can in VS.